# JWT functionality works locally but not on heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, jwt, authorization

So I'm currently building a todo app with nodejs, express, mongodb, jwt and hbs. I got everything to work locally, but when I finally deployed my site to heroku, I either get an undentified token back or an internal server error (error code 500), in other words a "JWT invalid token error". So why doesn't it work when it's deployed, but does work locally? And how can I fix it.

When using this the token returns undefined

```
const authHeader = req.headers["cookie"].split(" ")[1]
console.log(authHeader)
if(authHeader !== undefined) {
    token = authHeader.substring(6)
    console.log(token)
}
```

but without that, and just using this, I get the whole token, but an JWT invalid token error.

```
const authHeader = req.headers["cookie"]
console.log(authHeader)
if(authHeader !== undefined) {
    token = authHeader.substring(6)
    console.log(token)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came accross the exact same issue today so I'll share my endeavours here:

- my env vars, referencing my jwt secret, were correctly set on heroku env (you can verify that by just console logging an env var and seeing it outputted on your terminal using `heroku logs --tail`)
- I had a valid jwt returned on login and signup of a user (you can verify that with the excellent https://jwt.io/ debugger)

So what was going on ? in the try/catch block of my auth middleware handling the jwt decoding part, I consoled error my error and I found out that... my app' deployed on Heroku did not have the same time zone than mine (deployment is in the US and I live in Europe) =>

[image: token expired error because of TZ]

I dont know if your problem is related to that but it may be worth to checking your token expiry settings and your deployed app' timezone settings